# Two integrals equal to Euler-Mascheroni constant not evaluating symbolically

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I'm trying to compute:

```
Integrate[(x - 1)/((1 - x*y)* Log[x*y]), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

and

```
Integrate[FractionalPart[1/x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

The first is the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma=0.577$, and the second is $1-\gamma$.

However, it seems that the integrals can only be calculated numerically and not symbolically in Mathematica, that is, the output is
[image]

Can these two integrals be calculated symbolically in Mathematica?

Answer (score 6):

It just means that Mathematica does not have these integrals in its database yet.

One way to solve the first integral may be using `Series`:

```
Table[Integrate[
  Series[(x - 1)/((1 - x*y)*Log[x*y]), {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n}] //Normal,
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}], {n, 0, 5}]

Table[HarmonicNumber[n + 1] - Log[n + 1], {n, 0, 5}] == %
Limit[HarmonicNumber[n + 1] - Log[n + 1], n -> ∞]
```

---

```
{1, 3/2 - Log[2], 11/6 - Log[3], 25/12 - Log[4], 137/60 - Log[5], 
 49/20 - Log[6]}

True

EulerGamma
```

As you can see there is a simple sequence `{Log[2], Log[3], Log[4], Log[5], ...}` and another sequence `{1, 3/2, 11/6, 25/12, 137/60, ...` which can be identified by:

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1, 3/2, 11/6, 25/12, 137/60, 49/20}, x] // FullSimplify
```

---

```
HarmonicNumber[x]
```

Then using `Limit` you can compute the integral.

I am not telling this is a rigorous proof but surely you can build on it.

---

---

For the second integral using ([Fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part), [Floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions))
$$\operatorname {frac} (x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor ,\;x>0$$ and $$\lfloor x\rfloor =x-{\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{\pi }}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {\sin(2\pi kx)}{k}}$$

you have $$\operatorname {frac} (x)=\frac{1}{2}-{\frac {1}{\pi }}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {\sin(2\pi kx)}{k}}$$

Then by code:

```
Integrate[1/2, {x, 0, 1}] - 
  1/π Sum[
    Integrate[Sin[2 π k 1/x]/k, {x, 0, 1}], {k, 1, ∞}] // FullSimplify
```

---

```
1 - EulerGamma
```